# Ember integration tests failing when running multiple at once

Tags: ember.js, mocha.js, ember-cli

I've run into a weird problem writing integration tests for my component. When I run each one individually, they pass. When I run multiple, the first one passes and the other ones fail. I think it has something to do with closure actions but I don't know.

Here's my component code

```
// components/game-nav-key.js
triggerKeyAction(code) {
  if (this.get('prevKeyCode').contains(code)) {
    this.sendAction('onPrevKey', true);
  } else if (this.get('nextKeyCode').contains(code)) {
    this.sendAction('onNextKey', true);
  } else if (this.get('openKeyCode').contains(code)) {
    this.sendAction('onOpenKey');
  }
},

didInsertElement() {
  var self = this;

  Ember.$('body').keydown(function(e) {
    self.triggerKeyAction(e.which);
  });

  Ember.$('body').keyup(function(e) {
  });
}
```

And my tests

```
// game-nav-key-test.js
it('tracks key commands and sends an action for K', function() {
  let spy = sinon.spy();
  this.set('gotoPrev', spy);
  this.render(hbs`
    {{game-nav-key onPrevKey=(action gotoPrev)}}
  `);

  triggerKeydown($('body'), 75);
  triggerKeyup($('body'), 75);

  sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);
  sinon.assert.calledWith(spy, true);
});

it('tracks key commands and sends an action for J', function() {
  let spy = sinon.spy();
  this.set('gotoNext', spy);
  this.render(hbs`
    {{game-nav-key onNextKey=(action gotoNext)}}
  `);

  triggerKeydown($('body'), 74);
  triggerKeyup($('body'), 74);

  sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);
  sinon.assert.calledWith(spy, true);
});

it('tracks key commands and sends an action for R', function() {
  let spy = sinon.spy();
  this.set('open', spy);
  this.render(hbs`
    {{game-nav-key onOpenKey=(action open)}}
  `);

  triggerKeydown($('body'), 82);
  triggerKeyup($('body'), 82);

  sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);
});
```

I removed all beforeEach's, so it's literally just those three tests. Like I said, each one passes individually, and when it is listed first, but the second two fail when run together. Note that using `console.log` statements I have verified that the code hits the line directly above each of the `this.sendAction` calls in their respective tests

Comment: Looks like you're rebinding your listener every time the component mounts, and never unbinding on unmount.

Comment: Yup, that did it! Thanks! Want to answer so I can mark as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you need to destroy your listeners created in `didInsertElement`

---

```
willDestroyElement() {
    Ember.$('body').off('keydown');
    Ember.$('body').off('keyup');
}
```